# Adding class to the webform submit button

Tags: 7, webforms

By default, the web form is displayed with `<?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']); ?>` .

I need to make a small edit and add `class="btn"` to the `submit` button.

I can change its value with `$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "click to become a member";`

But I couldnt find a way to add the class.

Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to do something like this (add an array):

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "click to become a member", array('attributes' => array('class' => array('btn'), 'style' => array('CUSTOM STYLE DIRECTLY') ));
```

I'm not really sure if is there is the right place the you have to add that code, but that generally it's this code:

```
, array('attributes' => array('class' => array('btn'), 'style' => array('CUSTOM STYLE DIRECTLY') ))
```

Comment: I get syntax error with this code.

Comment: Ok, it's normal. Can you provide more details of code that you are working on? Copy the block code or the function and paste it here that i can analyze it.